# How to create stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to be able to create a stacked bar chart but when I change the stat ="identity" i get an error: ***"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): object 'prop' not found"***

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    ggplot(data = wq,aes(x=WHO_Risk_Level,group=1))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=..prop..,fill=factor(..x..)),stat ="count")+
  labs(y="Percent",x="WHO Risk Level")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
  guides(
    fill=FALSE
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can stack it when you specify x to be the factor.. One way to count first and plot:

```
set.seed(111)
wq = data.frame(WHO_Risk_Level=sample(c("High","Intermediate","Low"),1000,
prob=c(0.25,0.35,0.4),replace=TRUE))

library(dplyr)

wq %>% 
count(WHO_Risk_Level) %>% 
mutate(proportion=100*n/sum(n)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=1,y=proportion,fill=WHO_Risk_Level)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the argument you need is position = "stack". The stat = "identity" will make the bar chart a count of things on the y axis whereas stat = "bin" will be like a histogram. Try position = "stack" within geom_bar()
It looks to me like position = "dodge" is a default here

```
ggplot(data = wq,aes(x=WHO_Risk_Level,group=1))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=..prop..,fill=factor(..x..)),stat ="count", position = "stack")+
  labs(y="Percent",x="WHO Risk Level")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
  guides(
    fill=FALSE
```

)